# Oracle cloud REST API WaasPolicy and auditEvents pagination

Tags: python, oracle, api, rest, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to figure out the exact query string to successfully get the next page of results for both the waasPolicy logs and auditEvents logs. I have successfully made a query to both endpoints and returned data but the documentation does not provide any examples of how to do pagination.

my example endpoint url string:

```
https://audit.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/20190901/auditEvents?compartmentId={}&startTime=2021-02-01T00:22:00Z&endTime=2021-02-10T00:22:00Z
```

I have of course omitted my compartmentId. When I perform a GET request against this url, it successfully returns data. In order to paginate, the documentation states:
"Make a new GET request against the same URL, modified by setting the page query parameter to the value from the opc-next-page header. Repeat this process until you get a response without an opc-next-page header. The absence of this header indicates that you have reached the last page of the list."

My question is what exactly is this meant to look like? An example would be very helpful. The response header 'opc-next-page' for the auditEvents pagination contains a very long string of characters. Am I meant to append this to the url in the GET request? Would it simply be something like this? of course replacing $('opc-next-page') with that long string in the header.

```
https://audit.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/20190901/auditEvents?compartmentId={}&startTime=2021-02-01T00:22:00Z&endTime=2021-02-10T00:22:00Z&page=$(opc-next-page)
```

And the query for waasPolicy:

```
https://waas.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/20181116/waasPolicies/{}/wafLogs
```

returns an opc-next-page header in the form of a page number. Would it simply require appending something like &page=2? (Tried this to no avail)

Again, I am not able to find any examples in the documentation.

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/waas/20181116/WaasPolicy/GetWaasPolicy

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/usingapi.htm#nine

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Needed to specify &page=$(opc-next-page) AND specify a &limit=X (where x = any integer i.e. 500) parameter. Without the limit param, the &page= param returns a 500 error which is slightly misleading. Will leave this up for anyone else stumbling upon this issue.